# How to use Simple Moving average for N step forecast on unobserved data

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, moving-average

I have a confusion about how to forecast future steps using MA. All the articles out there validate the model by only considering the historical data that were OBSERVED. However, once we validate an MA model has a good performance on our train data, we need to set up a pipeline for future forecats.

The problem is that for n-step ahead future forecast, all the data is observed only for the first forecast. What happens to the other n-1 steps? Here is an example.

Lets say we have a dataset from Jan 2021 to June 2022 and based on our experiments, we noticed a moving average using the last 3 values leads to the best error for a 3-step ahead forecast horizon.

Now we want to forecast for July, August and September. For July, we already observed the prior 3 months values so we can get a mean of that and its the forecast. However, actual July data is missing for August forecast. What happens here? Should we consider the forecasted value for July and the actuals for June and May to find the value for August?

I am sorry if my question is trivial but I am trying to code it myself in python so I want to make sure I am doing it the right way.

Comment: are you asking how to test your MA model? are you using a train test split?

Comment: I have tested my model. My question is about forecast in future. When we want to forecast n steps in future and we have not observed any of those data yet, how do we forecast for step 2 and so on. Step 1 is easy because all of the previous data has been observed

Comment: Not sure what your intention here is, are trying to create a time series model? Can you give details on what this MA is used for, is this an input to a forecasting model?

Comment: It basically is using a simple moving average to forecast future. So lets say we will consider the past 3 observations and get average of that as the forecast. Does that make sense?